# O365 REST API Error Response for Version method

Tags: rest, sharepoint

Large Files in Microsoft Office 365 SharePoint **do not** support Versions request.

I've isolated the problem to the file size. This is a sharepoint deployment on Microsoft O365.

The *issue* seems to be with `Microsoft’ Rest API` and it appears to be related to the size of the file. This makes no sense to me, but my test data reflects these facts.

When I request Version I receive this response, **but only for files that are *greater than 1 GB* in size**:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

*I've tried Microsoft support and they have provided no help in regards to the error message or how to change the state of the object.*

Any insights from the community would be greatly appreciated as this error has stopped my migration between sites dead in its tracks.

## My tests

*The file is unlocked. It is visible and checked in to the users. I have administrative privileges. A very simple versions GET results in an error.*

### Test 1:  Does the format of the file make any difference?

***Step 1***: I zipped the ISO file and stored it in the same location.

***Step 2***: When I used the REST API to explore the versions, I was presented with the same error:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

### Test 2: Is the file corrupt in some way?

***Step 1***: Upload the .ISO file to the same location with a new name.

***Step 2***: when I used the REST AP to explore the versions, I was presented with the same error:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

### Test 3: Is the error related to size?

***Step 1***: I created a small program to generate a text file, which repeats a text string, `This is a test string that is 4`, over and over again for the size of the file in gigabytes.

***Step 2***: Create a 1 GB file, *test.txt*

***Step 3***: create a 4 GB file, *test4.txt*

***Step 4***: Transfer files to the folder.

***Step 5***: Use the `REST API` to retrieve *test.txt* versions, **it works**.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed  ...`

***Step 6***: Use the `REST API` to retrieve the *test4.txt* versions, **it fails**:

> ```
> <m:error
> xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
> <m:code>-1, System.InvalidOperationException</m:code> <m:message
> xml:lang="en-US"> Operation is not valid due to the current state of
> the object. </m:message> </m:error>
> ```

This leads me to believe that the O365 implementation of Sharepoint has a size related issue. In the past, there has been a problem with files over 2GB in size but today Microsoft claims that up to 30 GB can be stored in a single file:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/File-size-limits-for-workbooks-in-SharePoint-Online-9E5BC6F8-018F-415A-B890-5452687B325E

Given that all of my files are within the guidance provided by Microsoft, all of the files should behave in the same manner.

---

## From the Microsoft site

What are the current file size limits for workbooks?

Your file size limits are determined by your particular subscription to Office 365.

If your Office 365 subscription includes…   And the workbook is stored here…    Then these file size limits apply to workbooks in a browser window

SharePoint Online   A library in a site such as a team site 0-30 MB
Outlook Web App Attached to an email message    0-10 MB

If you’re trying to open a workbook that is attached to an email message in Outlook Web App, a smaller file size limits applies. In this case, the workbook must be smaller than 10 MB to open in a browser window.

If you are using Excel Online and Power BI, different file size limits apply. For more information, see Data storage in Power BI and Reduce the size of a workbook for Power BI.

Here’s the REST API GET, it's very simple:

[https://oceusnetworks.sharepoint.com/opp/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/opp/Opportunities%202018/RPW%20Spectrum%20Prototype%20Technologies/03-Delivery/Deliverables/Software%20and%20License%20Keys/Windows/WIN2016-SESS_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9.ISO')/Versions](https://oceusnetworks.sharepoint.com/opp/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(%27/opp/Opportunities%202018/RPW%20Spectrum%20Prototype%20Technologies/03-Delivery/Deliverables/Software%20and%20License%20Keys/Windows/WIN2016-SESS_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9.ISO%27)/Versions)

Here’s the URL:

[https://oceusnetworks.sharepoint.com/opp/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/opp/Opportunities%202018/RPW%20Spectrum%20Prototype%20Technologies/03-Delivery/Deliverables/Software%20and%20License%20Keys/Windows/WIN2016-SESS_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9.ISO')/Versions](https://oceusnetworks.sharepoint.com/opp/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(%27/opp/Opportunities%202018/RPW%20Spectrum%20Prototype%20Technologies/03-Delivery/Deliverables/Software%20and%20License%20Keys/Windows/WIN2016-SESS_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9.ISO%27)/Versions)

and the response:

> ```
> <m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
> <m:code>-1, System.InvalidOperationException</m:code>
> <m:message xml:lang="en-US">
> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
> </m:message>
> </m:error>
> ```

Another file in the same directory:

[https://oceusnetworks.sharepoint.com/opp/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/opp/Opportunities%202018/RPW%20Spectrum%20Prototype%20Technologies/03-Delivery/Deliverables/Software%20and%20License%20Keys/Windows/WIN2016-SESS_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9.MDS')/Versions](https://oceusnetworks.sharepoint.com/opp/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(%27/opp/Opportunities%202018/RPW%20Spectrum%20Prototype%20Technologies/03-Delivery/Deliverables/Software%20and%20License%20Keys/Windows/WIN2016-SESS_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9.MDS%27)/Versions)

with the expected response (XML response truncated for brevity):

`< ? xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed ...  ></feed>`

Comment: Last line- `with the expected response:` is your **question incomplete**? By the way, welcome to SO. Please take time and visit [SO Asking Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and must read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the same. Please be **specific** to your question and ask it with proper formation

Comment: yes, i placed some formatted XML (the expected response), but this was not displayed in the forum.  I've added some strategic spaces to make the text show up here.

Comment: Has anyone tried to reproduce this effect on O365?  Is there a method to get help from Microsoft developers ? I think this is a problem in the API either a problem in the function or a problem in my use.

Answer (score 0):

This issue still happen with SharePoint Online (Microsoft 365). I managed to reproduce it with CSOM.

This will throw an exception for files > 4GB:

```
context.Load(listItem.File.Versions
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

It throws: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: HResult -2146233088 Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Luckily there is a workaround, just request specific properties and not the entire Version object:

```
context.Load(listItem.File.Versions,
                            versions => versions.Include(
                                version => version.VersionLabel,
                                version => version.IsCurrentVersion));
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

For me this work without any issue for files > 4GB.